# Why using .Result in ASP.NET Core doesn't produce deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, task

I have read [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and from what I understand, calling `.Result` on the Task received from an async method should produce a deadlock on one of the controller's actions.

I have the following code on which I have tried to reproduce what should have behaved like a deadlock:

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<string> Get()
{
    return GetSomeValue().Result.ToString();
}

private async Task<JObject> GetSomeValue()
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var jsonString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://localhost:44316/api/values");
        return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
    }
}
```

On the `https://localhost:44316/api/values` I have another Web Application that simply returns me a valid json.

The code runs flawlessly even though as stated in the article, it should produce a deadlock as the continuation of the `GetStringAsync` method should be waiting for the ASP.NET context which should be held by the first `Get` method (the request thread).

***Why I am not able to reproduce the deadlock described in the article, what am I missing?***

Comment: I believe .net core by default does not use a synchronization context

Comment: You are using ASP.NET Core, which was not existing at the time of the article. The way  threads are used is not the same (no more sync context). I can't guarantee you this is the cause, but probably a good place to start.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't have a synchronisation context, therefore everything after an await is run on a different thread. ASP.NET has a synchronisation context which forces everything after an await (without a ContinueWith(false)) do run on the calling thread. However, you still shouldn't use Result or Wait in code and always aim for "async all the way down".

Comment: still, don't play with fire and write `public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetAsync()` and `return (await GetSomeValue()).ToString()` instead ;)

Comment: @Pac0 thank you for the comments, they are really helpful. That article is indeed old and was targeting maybe .Net Framework, but I am still waiting for somebody to post an answer to the question :)

Comment: [Here's an update specifically addressing ASP.NET Core](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article is referring to the behavior of a *particular* sync context in ASP.NET; it doesn't apply to .NET Core at all, and even in ASP.NET this has been changed in more recent times to one that is more sympathetic to the TPL, but I suspect that if you configure ASP.NET (not "Core") with either:

```xml
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
```

or:

```xml
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

then you'll see the behavior being discussed.

However! You still **should not do what you are doing**; it is a terrible idea to access `.Result` unless you *know* a task is completed; `await` is the preferred mechanism. Just because it doesn't explode *in this case* doesn't mean it is OK to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, Marc! So, if I may, when I am calling `async` methods in ASP.NET (Core) I should be propagating the `async` `await` chain until it reaches the controller action, making it `async` too?

Comment: @meJustAndrew yes, exactly that